# Set google play services in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-api-client

I am following these two links to set up the play services

[Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

[Accessing Google APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#Starting)

But it is unable to find google api client class

THis is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.wishygupta.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wishygupta.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any exception thrown ? Is there any import statement or code showing error?

Comment: No exception thrown. Import for private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient; is not accessible. I mean it is not imported

Answer (score 0):

As it is recommended by Google also, try to use + sign for subversion of support library and google play service as following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure you have downloaded the latest Play Services SDK version 22 under Extras is installed.

Sample dependency section in my grade file.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
}
```